# Select subsets from List[Int] by increasing length upto List[Int] length

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a List of integers as:

```
val list= List(5,-2,10,-1,4)
```

And I want the desired result as a List of following subsets from the *list*

```
List(
(5),
(5,-2),
(5,-2,10),
(5,-2,10,-1),
(5,-2,10,-1,4),
(-2,10,-1,4),
(10,-1,4),
(-1,4),
(4)
)
```

How can I write a code using functional programming aspect of Scala?
Or by using any `for loop` constructs?

Comment: If the order doesn't matter and there will not be duplicates, my answer can help. If you require the order and preserve duplicates, let me known to delete my answer.

Comment: Apparently OP doesn't want all subsets, but some sort of window sliding over the list: start adding elements one by one from left to right and then remove them from left to right one by one.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok oh right, subsets would include more combinations, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact result as you want can be achieved by

```
val part1 = for (i <- (1 to list.size)) yield list.take(i)
val part2 = for (i <- (1 until list.size)) yield list.drop(i)
(part1 ++ part2).toList
```

If you want one-liner then:

```
( (1 to list.size).map(list.take) ++ (1 until list.size).map(list.take) ).toList
```

Comment: perfect. It works fine. Just that it returns a list of lists and not a list of tuples. Served the exact purpose though. @Mateusz Thanks!

Comment: @Harshv A list of tuples wouldn't work, because each tuple would have different sizes, so it would end up being a **List[Any]**.

Answer (score 3):

As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html) is your friend.

```
list.toSet.subSets.map(_.toList).toList
```

*(Note, since this is an expressive operation, it may be better to use the **Iterator** that `subsets` returns, instead of consuming it all once into a big list of lists)*